# How to do load, shuffle, batch from separate feature and labels csv in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

Current api [tf.experimental.make_csv_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset) takes in shuffle, batch and shuffle_buffer_size as the arguments so if i have separate `x_train` and `y_train` files my only options are:

1. I merge the two files manually and save on disk and then operate on that file
2. something like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    'data/x_train.csv',10000, column_names=colnames,prefetch_buffer_size=1,
shuffle=False,shuffle_buffer_size=10000)
labels = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    'data/y_train.csv',10000, column_names=labs.columns,prefetch_buffer_size=1,
shuffle=False,shuffle_buffer_size=10000)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset,labels)).shuffle(10000).batch(32)
```

which is horrendous i suppose. Inelegant and fills up shuffle buffer twice where it was necessary to do that just once.

Please help me find a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need a shuffle buffer if `shuffle=False` ?

Comment: that buffer will feed into the chained `shuffle` that has a buffer of 10000. If that is not the case then there would not be enough samples coming downstream from dataset to fill up 10k buffer... am i right in understanding the way tf.data.Dataset works?

Comment: `tf.data.Dataset.zip()` returns a `tf.data.Dataset`, so it pulls the data that it needs during runtime. No need for a shuffle buffer on your 2 datasets.As for your question, I don't see nothing wrong with the way you did it. Juste make extra sure your labels still corresponds with the data. It's the only risk there is.